# If condition combined with vlookup not working in google sheets

Tags: google-docs

This is my function in google sheet:

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H2)),vlookup(H2,Tags!A2:B64,2,FALSE),'')` and that's giving me the error: `Formula parse error.`

the function `vlookup(H2,Tags!A2:B64,2,FALSE)` works on its own however and returns a correct value

I'm sure that the syntax is correct but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the '' changing them to "" worked.
The correct query is:
`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H2)),vlookup(H2,Tags!A2:B64,2,FALSE),"")`